# The need for an "else" statement if the "if" statement has the die command

Tags: php

If the "if" block ends unconditionally with a "die" command, is there any need for an "else" block (since if the statement was true, the php script exits, and if it's false, the else block would be executed regardless)?

I'm working with something that has an "else" block in this situation and I was wondering if cleaning that up would actually affect anything.

Comment: there's no problem with having an `else` block in this case (i.e. you won't get any errors), but the contents of the `else` block will never be executed. because it would never be executed anyway, deleting the `else` block will do absolutely nothing at all (except clean up your code)

Comment: The else block WOULD execute; in fact it seems to be superfluous as it could just be put in the normal program flow.

Comment: ohh i see what you mean. yeah, put the contents of the `else` block outside the block entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($condition)
{
    echo ("one");
    die();
}
else
{
    echo ("two");
}
```

**should be**:

```
if ($condition)
{
    echo ("one");
    die(); // or return
}
echo ("two");
```

**It's shorter, easier on the eyes** and does the same thing. When an `if` block is **terminal** (`die` or `return`), there's no point in an else as that's the normal code flow anyways.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing that requires you to have an else block at all regardless of whether you have `die()` command or not.

Comment: So you wonder whether you can safely remove the else block without breaking application?  Hard to say without knowing what is in the code.  If you are confident that the if condition will always be triggered (in which case I would wonder why there is an if at all), then by all means remove the else as that code path would never be followed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code :

```
if ($condition)
{
    echo ("one");
    die();
}
else
{
    echo ("two");
}

echo ("three");
```

If your condition is true, it will echo "one". If your condition is false, it will echo "twothree".

The code only dies if it is reached, if your condition is false, it will never go inside the If brackets, so it will not die.

You don't need to remove the code inside the else, the code in it will never be executed. Yes, the code will be there, but code that isn't execute will not affect performance.

Comment: If you removed the else block and made the 'echo("two");' part of the normal flow, would it change anything?

Comment: No it would not change anything, it would have the same result in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To add in to Mike's answer, if you're doing

```
if ($myVar = 1) {
 // do something
 die();
}
if($myVar = 2){
 // do something
 die();
}
```

it may be  better to do a switch:

```
$destination = "Tokyo";
echo "Traveling to $destination<br />";
switch ($destination){
    case "Las Vegas":
        echo "Bring an extra $500";
        break;
    case "Amsterdam":
        echo "Bring an open mind";
        break;  
    case "Egypt":
        echo "Bring 15 bottles of SPF 50 Sunscreen";
        break;  
    case "Tokyo":
        echo "Bring lots of money";
        break;
    case "Caribbean Islands":
        echo "Bring a swimsuit";
        break;  
}
```

[stolen from Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/switch.php)

*written just after Mike's answer*